# Jquery "Open url after function completet"

Tags: jquery

Hello
I'm working on this page where i wan't to open a url after the animation is completet.

I have this but it dosen't seem to work. I'm tottaly new in Jquery.

```
$('h1').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().animate({
  "width" : "100%",
  "height" : "900px"
}, function() {
 $(this).load('index2.html');
});
```

Comment: does the animation work? or nothing happens at all?

Comment: Yes the animation works fine, but i don't want it to load in the same document but like when you click on an a link.

Comment: I think that you need to do opposite – first load html and then animate it.

Comment: please, clarify, do you want the animation on the FRESHLY LOADED html or on the old one?

Comment: I have my index.html with a box when i click it it becomes big, and after that animation i want to load the my second html but not into my index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
$('h1').click(function() {
 $(this).parent().animate({
  "width" : "100%",
  "height" : "900px"
 }, { complete: function() { $(this).load('index2.html'); }
});
```